# Postfix relay mails not from "mynetwork" or "authenticated users"

Tags: postfix, smarthost, relay

I have some trouble understanding Postfix-configuration and have the current situation:

I had one server with Plesk using Postfix as primary MX for several domains. Now - to reduce spam - I want to use mailcow on a second server as primary MX relaying mails to the Postfix. Mailcow is working and relaying the e-mails to the Postfix as expected, but: DNS-Entries for MX had a TTL of 300 seconds and should have been outdated everywhere (I know that some DNS-hosts keep information longer then TTL), but it's now days and I still receive mails on the former primary MX, Postfix without going through mailcow.

I would guess there should be some smart option to relay all mails not sent from "mynetwork" or an authenticated user from postfix to Mailcow so it should come back from Mailcow (which is in "mynetworks"), but I'm not able to figure out how to configure Postfix to work like this.

I found several examples on "how to configure Postfix as relay" and also many how tos to configure Postfix as local MTA, but I need something from both parts.

So in short: If a mail comes in from "mynetwork" it should be delivered to the local mailbox, if it was sent by an authenticated user it should be routed accordingly (local or external dependent on the destination ;) ), if neither of this applies all should be sent to the Mailcow (if possible already "filtert" by the locally available mailboxes).

Hope my situation was well described and someone can push me in the right direction. Maybe it's again a situation of "wrong search terms" to find the correct answer - or such a specific use-case that nobody had before!? :)

Kind regards

EDIT:

Thank you for the response. Here is the content, I only changed the domain-names to dummy domains. The question is not really related to Plesk, I want to change Postfix on the config-file-level to work as described above, but delivery to local postboxes should still be possible. There must be a way to configure Postfix to work like I want without changing the Plesk-part to work (management of the postboxes itself). Hope there is a solution I can use :)

postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
authorized_flush_users =
authorized_mailq_users =
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
message_size_limit = 30720000
mydestination = localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = server.domain.tld
mynetworks =
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
readme_directory = no
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient,header_recipient
recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:12346
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.pem
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /opt/psa/etc/dhparams2048.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtputf8_enable = no
tls_medium_cipherlist = EECDH+AESGCM+AES128:EECDH+AESGCM+AES256:EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+SHA256+AES128:EECDH+SHA384+AES256:EECDH+SHA1+AES128:EECDH+SHA1+AES256:EECDH+HIGH:AESGCM+AES128:AESGCM+AES256:CHACHA20:SHA256+AES128:SHA256+AES256:SHA1+AES128:SHA1+AES256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!KRB5:!aECDH:!kDH:!EDH
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/certs
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
```

postconf -M:

```
smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog    unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRXhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=R user=list:list argv=/usr/lib/plesk-9.0/postfix-mailman ${nexthop} ${user} ${recipient}
plesk_virtual unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DORhu user=popuser:popuser argv=/usr/lib/plesk-9.0/postfix-local -f ${sender} -d ${recipient} -p /var/qmail/mailnames -q ${queue_id}
127.0.0.1:12346 inet n   n       n       -       -       spawn user=popuser:popuser argv=/usr/lib/plesk-9.0/postfix-srs
pickup     fifo  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
qmgr       fifo  n       -       n       1       1       qmgr
smtps      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
plesk_saslauthd unix y   y       y       -       1       plesk_saslauthd status=5 listen=6 dbpath=/plesk/passwd.db
submission inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
plesk-domain1.tld-1.2.3.4- unix - - n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=1.2.3.4 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4 -o inet_protocols=ipv4 -o smtp_helo_name=domain1.tld
plesk-domain2.tld-1.2.3.4- unix - - n -     -       smtp -o smtp_bind_address=1.2.3.4 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4 -o inet_protocols=ipv4 -o smtp_helo_name=domain2.tld
plesk-domain3.tld-1.2.3.4- unix - - n -       -       smtp -o smtp_bind_address=1.2.3.4 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4 -o inet_protocols=ipv4 -o smtp_helo_name=domain3.tld
[...]
plesk-domainn.tld-1.2.3.4- unix - - n - -      smtp -o smtp_bind_address=1.2.3.4 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4 -o inet_protocols=ipv4 -o smtp_helo_name=domainn.tld
```

So to summarize up what I want to achieve:

1. SMTP from MX --> For local domains --> Handle according to configured postbox
2. SMTP from authenticated user --> Relay direct to destination
3. SMTP from anywhere else (not MX as source, nor authenticated user) --> For local domains --> Relay to MX

Hope this summarizes it a bit up? :)

Thank you so far!

Comment: If you are ready to configure Postfix the way it is supposed to and documented, by editing its configuration files, you're welcome. Then please provide your current configuration by adding [into the question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1145147/edit) the output of `postconf -n` (non-default content of main.cf) and `postconf -M` (content of master.cf). Note that we won't help with anything Plesk-specific and won't adapt any our recommendations to be compatible with Plesk; web control panels are declared off topic on ServerFault exactly for this reason.

Comment: Thank you, have edited my question with wanted information.